# Sublime Text 3 ; Conda Environment

Tags: anaconda, sublimetext3, python-3.7

I am extremely new to creating environments, and i'm having issues setting the directory path to the correct location. I have Anaconda install on this machine.

**By default, it looks like it is going here:**

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/Users/examplename/anaconda3/bin/python' [cmd:
>   ['/Users/examplename/anaconda3/bin/python', '-u',
>   '/Users/examplename/Desktop/python_work/test_pyenvironment.py']] [dir:
>   /Users/examplename/Desktop/python_work] [path:
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

**When my anaconda file location is actually in:**

```
'MacintoshHD/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

Does anyone know how I can change where Sublime Text is looking, when trying to find this root folder? I'm not too sure about the PATH either, 'usr/bin:/bin:etc.' doesn't seem right?

Comment: Can you explain under which circumstances Sublime should look anywhere? Isn't that a simple text editor?

Comment: in order to use the libraries/modules in Anaconda's folder (i.e. Pandas), I think it has to point to that directory. Yes it is a simple text editor. 
I've already installed the Package Manager / Conda build with it, just can't seem to point it to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using your main anaconda env with pandas installed, you need to set a build system for your anaconda env. Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921300/7170965) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54938217/7170965) you need to go to `Tools ▶ Build System ▶ New Build System` and set your custom build system:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "~/anaconda3/bin/python -u $file",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
}
```

And to use this custom build you have to select either `Tools ▶ Build System ▶ Automatic` or `Tools ▶ Build System ▶ <your-custom-build-system-name>` before building your code and/or to satisfy the Anaconda package for sublime.