# Cannot use Ananconda Interpreter in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, sublimetext3

I want to use Sublime Text 3 as my Python editor but cannot figure out how to make Anaconda its default interpreter for Python. To make sure that Anaconda is added to the path correctly, in the terminal I typed

> $ which python

Terminal returns

> /home/rahit/anaconda3/bin/python

But when I type a code like this in ST 3

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

The output in the Sublime console will be

> /usr/bin/python

Now if I type

`import pandas as pd`

There will be always an error

> ImportError: No module named pandas
>   [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: python -u "/home/rahit/Documents/Python/pro.py"]
>   [dir: /home/rahit/Documents/Python]
>   [path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/> usr/local/games:/opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin]`

Apart from these whenever I launch Sublime Text 3, many a times I get a message saying

`<Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_process.LocalProcess object at 0x7f248c4eab90> process can not start a new anaconda JsonServer in the operating system because:`

**Anaconda can not spawn a new process with your current configured python interpreter (/home/rahit/anaconda/bin/python)
Make sure your interpreter is a valid binary and is in your PATH or use an absolute path to it, for example: /usr/bin/python**

I have seen there are already some questions asked on these topic but none of them actually solved my problem. I have also seen people similar discussions on github from which I have ended up concluding that Conda cannot be used with ST3. For the final time I just want to know if there is any way to fix this problem cause I really want to use ST3 for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the build system that sublime uses, it uses your default python executable.

If you go to Tools ▶ Build System ▶ New Build System… and then you can define your own build system that uses the anaconda executable. It should look like the following

```
{
    'cmd': ['/usr/bin/python3', '-u', '$file'],
    'file_regex': '^[ ]*File "(…*?)", line ([0-9]*)',
    'selector': 'source.python'
}
```

Then just replace the path with the path of your anaconda executable

Comment: I have done it. Replaced '/usr/bin/python3'  with '/home/rahit/anaconda3/bin/python'. Then chose that newly created build system. Relaunched Sublime. Now it tells me **No Build System** when I try to run my code.

Comment: Have you selected it again after relaunching ?

Comment: Yes. But Sublime console still showing 'No Build System'. The message "Anaconda cannot spawn a new process...." is still popping up when launching Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [@Shadesfear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921300/7170965)'s answer, to use this custom build you have to select either `Tools ▶ Build System ▶ Automatic` or `Tools ▶ Build System ▶ <your-custom-build-system-name>` before building your code.

Also, you can replace the `cmd` command with `"shell_cmd": "~/anaconda3/bin/python -u $file",` at your `.sublime-build` file because it is cleanner and allow you to use pipes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Apart from the 'Anaconda cannot spawn a new process ...' pop-up all other problems has been fixed. Anaconda interpreter is now working fine with Sublime.